# WPF set new value to my ListView Progress-Bar column

Tags: wpf, listview, binding, progress-bar

I have this `Progress-Bar` inside my `ListView Column`:

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="-6">
            <ProgressBar Name="progressBarColumn" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Progress, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                     Width="{Binding Path=Width, ElementName=ProgressCell}" 
                     Height="18" Margin="0" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=progressBarColumn, StringFormat={}{0}%}" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="11"  />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.Resources>
```

This `Progress-Bar` is binding into my `Collection` into my Progress `Property`.
Now when my work finished and i want another loop i want to reset all this `Progress-Bar` value to zero so how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the Progress property in your source type implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Once you do that, then you can iterate through your collection, reset your Progress properties to 0 and your ListView should update.